# Quality of RegionIntersection[]: How to control?

Tags: graphics3d, regions

This code produces a crude intersection.

```
a = {-1/2, -1/2, -1/2};
b = {1/2, 1/2, 1/2};
R = RegionIntersection[Ball[a, 1], Ball[b, 1]];
Region[R]
```

---

[image: TwoBallsInt]

---

How can I control the quality so that the intersection is cleaner?

Comment: Slightly better, but with persistent artifacts: `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[Ball[{-1/2, -1/2, -1/2}, 1], Ball[{1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, 1]], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.01}]`.

Comment: I think the result only *looks* bad.  `R` still represents the proper (undiscretzied) region.  `Region` just doesn't display it in a nice way.

Comment: Very nice, @J.M.---Thanks!

Comment: a work-around: `RegionPlot3D[RegionMember[R, {x, y, z}], {x, -1/2, 1/2}, {y, -1/2, 1/2}, {z, -1/2, 1/2}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 100]`

Comment: `CSGRegion["Intersection", {Ball[a, 1], Ball[b, 1]}]`